# Toggle visible list items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, select, hide, show

I have multiple unordered lists on my page. In each list, I want to show only the first five list items by default, then have a link that toggles the display of the remaining items on and off.

I started off with this:

`$("ul li").slice(5).hide();`

But that ends up hiding all items in all lists except for the first five in the first list, because they all get counted together.

How can I do this but have it affect each list individually (note that I can't add unique IDs to each list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `each` function to do this for each and every `<ul>` you have. Try something like this:

```
$("ul").each(function(){
  $(this).children().slice(5).hide();
});
```

Then use some code like this to show them all:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   $("ul").each(function(){
      $(this).children().show();
   });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/F8ByE/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each `ul` elements and then hide `li` elements

```
$("ul").each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:gt(5)').hide();
});
```